# BSOD after adding an extra RAM

Tags: windows-7, laptop, memory, bsod

A couple of months ago I have decided to add an 8G extra RAM to my laptop
from same brand (Samsung) with same specs. Since then, I have get BSOD from time to time even multiple of times in a day. I have applied common remedies such as trying to update my Windows, running SFC scan, swapping RAM slots, uninstalling antivirus, running memtest(passed for the first 8 tests and left cause it was too long) etc. I had similar problems 3 years ago with seams laptop (but without extra RAM) and after uninstalling my antivirus (Bulldog) it went away. Nonetheless, this time the error seems serious and haven't gone yet.

P.S: For the fact I wanted to replace the fan and keyboard as well, I took my laptop to a shop and the owner used force-shutdown a couple of times even during disk check and "resuming windows" phase.

RAMs are identical except the 8G one is dual channel.

**EDIT**

I have used a dump file viewer and based the info that is shown by the viewer, for 9 BSOD the cause is `ntoskml.exe`, for one BSOD the cause is `ndisrd.sys` for one it is caused by `muclass.sys` and for one it is caused by `ntfs.sys`.

**EDIT2**

It may worth to mention that at the same time, firefox gets crashes quite often.

Comment: If you only run with the new module do you experience the same issues?

Comment: You should try it.  This is the first thing I would have tried to diagnose the problem.  However, without the specific BSOD and the dmp file that was created there really isn’t any way anyone here to properly diagnose this error.

Comment: @Ramhound consider the case where the BSOD is gone, Does it mean I cant use my other RAM?

Comment: Speculation isn’t productive.  Verify the problem is actually the memory then, proper answers can be submitted, speculation at this point wouldn’t be helpful to anyone

Comment: @Ramhound I remember for two BSOD that one was for MEMORY_MANAGEMENT nad the other one was for BAD_POOL_HEADER. I am not sure how to share the dump file since it is about 1GB.

Comment: You don’t share the file.  You use the tool to analyze the file, and provide the relevant information, from the generated file.  How you analyze a dmp file is well documented by both Microsoft and numerous questions here on this website.

Comment: @Ramhound Read my Edit please

Comment: The tool has misdiagnosed the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111961/discussion-between-user1064929-and-ramhound).